# UIImagePickerController startVideoCapture with native controls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using Phonegap's implementation to use the video capture and can't seem to get startVideoCapture to work. I'm a novice when it comes to Objective C, so I apologize if I'm off base here. Sounds like startVideoCapture is mainly for custom UI's. Is there something I can do to auto start the video recording (since I'm starting the video interface from another action). Here's a link to the full file:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCapture.m

Thanks,

Steve

```
- (void)captureVideo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSString* callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"hereeeee");
    if ([options isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    }

    // options could contain limit, duration and mode
    // taking more than one video (limit) is only supported if provide own controls via cameraOverlayView property
    NSNumber* duration = [options objectForKey:@"duration"];
    NSString* mediaType = nil;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        // there is a camera, it is available, make sure it can do movies
        pickerController = [[CDVImagePicker alloc] init];

        NSArray* types = nil;
        if ([UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(availableMediaTypesForSourceType:)]) {
            types = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
            // NSLog(@"MediaTypes: %@", [types description]);

            if ([types containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]) {
                mediaType = (NSString*)kUTTypeMovie;
            } else if ([types containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeVideo]) {
                mediaType = (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!mediaType) {
        // don't have video camera return error
        NSLog(@"Capture.captureVideo: video mode not available.");
        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageToErrorObject:CAPTURE_NOT_SUPPORTED];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:callbackId];
        pickerController = nil;
    } else {
        pickerController.delegate = self;
        pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        pickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        pickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        // iOS 3.0
        pickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mediaType, nil];

        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]) {
            if (duration) {
                pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = [duration doubleValue];
            }
            // NSLog(@"pickerController.videoMaximumDuration = %f", pickerController.videoMaximumDuration);
        }

        // iOS 4.0
        if ([pickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(cameraCaptureMode)]) {
            pickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
            // pickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
            // pickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
            // pickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        }
        // CDVImagePicker specific property
        pickerController.callbackId = callbackId;

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"presentViewController:animated:completion:");
        if ([self.viewController respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [self.viewController presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            // deprecated as of iOS >= 6.0
            [self.viewController presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
        }
        // Auto start capture
        [pickerController startVideoCapture];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem wasn't the use of startVideoRecording, it was when:

```
        [self.viewController presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:^(){
            [pickerController startVideoCapture];
        }];
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks,

Steve